# Generalization (?) of the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

The usual Implicit Function Theorem says that

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^{n+m}\to\Bbb{R}^m$ be a smooth function and let $\Bbb{R}^{n+m}$ have coordinates $(x,y)$. Fix a point $(a,b)$ with $f(a,b)=c$. If the derivative of $f$ is invertible then there exists an open set $U$ containing $a$, an open set $V$ containing $b$, and a unique smooth function $g:U\to V$ whose graph is the intersection of $U\times V$ and $f^{-1}(c)$.

Do we also have an implicit function theorem for smooth functions $\Bbb{R}^{n+m}\to\Bbb{R}^{n+m}$? I don't see why not, didn't encounter anywhere, though.

Comment: voilà: http://alexreinking.com/math/view/constant-rank-theorem

Comment: in the implicite function theorem the matrix would not have the zero-blocks at the bottom

Comment: I can't get your statement: how can be the derivative of $f$ invertible? Makes no sense when $n \neq 0$!

Comment: You have to precise, the derivative of $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{R}^m$... then, when $n=0$, you find the so-called local invertion theorem

Comment: it's not about invertibility, it's about rank.

Comment: i wrote something as comment to an answer but someone deleted the answer... now my comment is gone. what i wrote is about this (kind of vague stuff): the implicit function theorem is a statement about invertibility of the differential respective *some* components, the other ones have to be fix. then you get manifolds of dimension (dim image space - dim domain). we might try to generalise this for functions with higher dimension image domain but have to replace the invertibility criterion of the differential respective (dim image domain) coordinates, for example by a constant rank criterion